# Creating a Javascript Date object by passing in a date? What is a dateString?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what the W3C website means by dateString.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

I am trying to do something like:

```
var _date =  new Date("Mon Aug 12 2013 2:00 AM");
```

or even:

```
var _date =  new Date("Mon, Aug 12 2013, 2:00 AM");
```

Is there a quick way of turning my string into a format that the date object likes?

Thank you

edit:

I suppose it expects the following:

```
 var d = new Date()

d.toDateString()
"Tue Aug 13 2013"
```

Is it only that type of string?

Comment: The W3C website can be found at http://w3c.org/ — you are looking at the W3Schools website who are a [very poor](http://w3fools.com/) tutorial site that gets a lot of reflected glory from the W3C by virtue of having a similar name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript string-based Date constructor accepts strings in a format accepted by [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

These are date strings compliant with [RFC-2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) or [ISO-8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

Use String in this format:

```
new Date('2013-08-13')
```

or

```
new Date('2013-08-13T10:51:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is how to use dateString as a parameter

```
var dateString = "08/12/2013";
var d = new Date(dateString);
dateString = d.getFullYear() + "/" + d.getMonth() + "/" + d.getDate();
document.write(dateString);
```

Remember month are stored at 0th index in javascript.